# How to block multiple threads and wake them on a condition

Tags: c++, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I am trying to use the rcswitch API to read a value acquired by RF.
The standard code are working fine, but it is quite ugly :

```
while(1) {
    if (mySwitch.available()) {
        int value = mySwitch.getReceivedValue();

        if (value == 0) {
            printf("Unknown encoding\n");
        } else {    
            printf("Received %i\n", mySwitch.getReceivedValue() );
        }
        mySwitch.resetAvailable();
    }
}
```

(This is the RFSniffer.cpp code).
This loop is running continuously, and is consumming a lot of CPU.
I am looking for a solution to create a blocking function (equivalent of the getReceivedValue()) waiting for a value acquired in another function (in the RCSwitch.cpp file, it should be in the receiveProtocol1 and receiveProtocol2 functions).

I tried with mutex and lock but without success.
Could somebody help ?

Thanks

Comment: "I tried with mutex and lock but without success.  Well, what was the problem?

Comment: Does the rcswitch API provide for events allowing you to wait on an event or does it require polling?  What you have right now is a polling loop which just continually checks the `available()` method to see if there is something to do. If you must do polling then an alternative is to have a low priority thread that does the polling every few milliseconds. Then if the polling thread sees that `available()` is true it can do something constructive.  At a minimum add a thread sleep in your polling loop in order to let other threads get CPU time. Even better is to have it run at lower priority.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but this sounds a lot like the case for "Condition Variables"

Comment: Might be interesting to find out why the switch isn't available. That looks like the sort of code built around "nothing could go wrong with the hardware" thinking.

Comment: How is `mySwitch.available()` currently implemented?

Comment: according to github, `bool RCSwitch::available() {  return RCSwitch::nReceivedValue != NULL; }` More spelunking required.

Comment: @QuestionC Pretty simple set up. nReceivedValue is an unsigned long set when data arrives. No idea why it's being compared to NULL, easiest I guess. Could replace with a [condition variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) and a notify_all in the receiveProtocol1 and receiveProtocol2 functions.

Comment: Simplest is to do what @RichardChambers suggested and reduce the frequency of polling with sleep.